# How to rename the parent tag of string array in soap web service response using java

Tags: java, web-services, soap

I'm trying to send a string array in the response object. Everything seems perfect but the only problem is, in the response the array have a parent tag. Parent tag has the name which I gave for the string array in the response object and child have the same name. How I can remove this parent tag or rename the parent tag in the response.

**My Interface is like this**

```
@WebService
@SOAPBinding(style = Style.RPC)

public interface VAECorpService {

    @WebMethod 
    CommissionProfileResponse commissionProfile(@WebParam(name = "commissionProfile")CommissionProfileRequest commissionProfileReq);

}
```

**My response class is**

```
public class CommissionProfileResponse {

    private String statusCode;
    private String statusDes;
    private String[] commissionProfileId;

    public String getStatusCode() {
        return statusCode;
    }

    public void setStatusCode(String statusCode) {
        this.statusCode = statusCode;
    }

    public String getStatusDes() {
        return statusDes;
    }

    public void setStatusDes(String statusDes) {
        this.statusDes = statusDes;
    }

    public String[] getCommissionProfileId() {
        return commissionProfileId;
    }

    public void setCommissionProfileId(String[] commissionProfileId) {
        this.commissionProfileId = commissionProfileId;
    }
}
```

** This is my Service Impl**

```
   @Override
        public CommissionProfileResponse commissionProfile(CommissionProfileRequest commissionProfileReq) {

            CommissionProfileResponse commissionProfileResp=new CommissionProfileResponse();
            VAECorpDao vaECorpDao = DAOFactory.getVAECorpDao();
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            try{
                                 List<String>lstCommissionProf=vaECorpDao.getAllCommissionProfile(commissionProfileReq.getProductId());
                     String [] array=new String[lstCommissionProf.size()];
                     for (int i=0;i< lstCommissionProf.size();i++) {
                         array[i]=lstCommissionProf.get(i);
                    }
                     if(lstCommissionProf.size()>0){
                      commissionProfileResp.setStatusCode("I000000");
                      commissionProfileResp.setStatusDes("Success : Commission profile fetched successfully");
                      commissionProfileResp.setCommissionProfileId(array);
                     }
                     else{
                          commissionProfileResp.setStatusCode("I000000");
                          commissionProfileResp.setStatusDes("Success : No commission found");
                          commissionProfileResp.setCommissionProfileId(array);
                     }

            }
            catch(Exception e){
                  logger.info("commissionProfile VA-F0003");
                  logger.info("Fail : "+e.getMessage());
                  commissionProfileResp.setStatusCode("VA-F0003");
                  commissionProfileResp.setStatusDes("Fail : "+e.getMessage());
            }

            return commissionProfileResp;
        }
```

Now i getting response like this

```
  **<commissionProfileResponse xmlns="http://service.va.alfaris.com">
     <commissionProfileReturn>
        <commissionProfileId>
           <commissionProfileId>112233</commissionProfileId>
        </commissionProfileId>
        <statusCode>I000000</statusCode>
        <statusDes>Success : Commission profile fetched successfully</statusDes>
     </commissionProfileReturn>
  </commissionProfileResponse>**
```

I want the response like this

```
**<commissionProfileResponse xmlns="http://service.va.alfaris.com">
         <commissionProfileReturn>          
               <commissionProfileId>112233</commissionProfileId>           
            <statusCode>I000000</statusCode>
            <statusDes>Success : Commission profile fetched successfully</statusDes>
         </commissionProfileReturn>
      </commissionProfileResponse>**
```

and I want to change the name of the tag if possible both the request and the response. I already tried with @XMLELEMENT but it's not reflecting

Comment: What WS framework (JAX-WS, CXF, AXIS/AXIS2, etc.) do you use?

Comment: @m4gic- AXIS2 framework i'm currently using

Comment: Try by changing to String instead of String[] for commissionProfileId field.

Comment: if I change String instead of string[] then only last value will come in the response. I want to have an array of value in the response with the same tag name.